Add Deceleration to the player
So, I have a unique situation where I want the player to decelerate when you release your movement key however I don't want acceleration physics. I want the player to go max speed instantly while also decelerating when they stop moving.
My current movement code looks like this:
private float horizontal;
public float speed = 10;
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);   
}

Thank you to anyone who responds!

If you can find out whether the key is pressed, wouldn't it work to just hard set the velocity to a fixed amount? And then just use normal physics when the key is not pressed.

Yeah you could set rb.isKinematic = Mathf.Abs( horizontal ) > 0; and only hard set the velocity if it is not kinematic
